# why sqlite3_bind_* starts from index 1 but sqlite3_column_* starts from 0?

Tags: sqlite

in the comments from sqlite3.h:

for sqlite3_bind_*,
** ^The index for named parameters can be looked up using the
** [sqlite3_bind_parameter_index()] API if desired.  ^The index
** for "?NNN" parameters is the value of NNN.
** ^The NNN value must be between **1** and the [sqlite3_limit()]

for sqlite3_column_*
** ^The leftmost column of the result set has the index 0.
** ^The number of columns in the result can be determined using
** [sqlite3_column_count()].

Why there is such a weird inconsistency?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No weird inconsistency.

The `sqlite3_bind_*()` functions associate values with printf-style format specifiers ("host parameter names" in SQLite3's own terminology). Having a similar functionality to that of function arguments, it matches the convention to number them from 1 ("first argument", "second argument", ...).

A similarity: in POSIX C, the `printf()` function accepts format strings that can modify the order of conversions using the `%N$c` syntax, where `c` is the actual conversion specifier character or char sequence, and `N` is a number **starting from one.**

The columns, however, are not argument-like entities. They're rather items in an indexable data structure. They are more similar to, for example, the elements of an array, that's why it makes sense to start indexing them from zero.

Comment: +1 one for good explanation, but I do agree with OP that it's an inconsistency.

Comment: @SamuelNeff Thanks. Indeed, at the roots, it could be more consistent: we could pass the 0th argument to a function.